# Set vtkLookupTable on Volume DICOM Images

Tags: c++, vtk, dicom

I got MIP(Maximum Intensity Projection) and other volumes in medical project for viewing `dicom` images.
For making the volume i use:

- `vtkVolume`
- `vtkSmartVolumeMapper`

I need to set/change `vtkLookupTable` to the volume, but can not find appropriate way. Can someone with more experience into vtk explain me how can i add/set/change `vtkLookupTable` on `vtkSmartVolumeMapper`

Answer (score 2):

You may check the class [vtkDiscretizableColorTransferFunction](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDiscretizableColorTransferFunction.html#details)

it is a combination of vtkColorTransferFunction and vtkLookupTable.

e.g.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDiscretizableColorTransferFunction> discretizableColorTransferFunction = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDiscretizableColorTransferFunction>::New();

discretizableColorTransferFunction->DiscretizeOn();
discretizableColorTransferFunction->SetNumberOfValues(10);
discretizableColorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(10.0, 0, 1, 0);
discretizableColorTransferFunction->Build();

volumeProperty->SetColor(discretizableColorTransferFunction);

volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);
```

Comment: I implemented but dont have the same effect like vtkLookupTable how can i create vtkDiscretizableColorTransferFunction identical (to get the same effect from vtkLookupTable) lets say for this example:
`vtkLookupTable* lut = vtkLookupTable::New(); 
   lut->SetNumberOfTableValues(256); 
   lut->Build(); 

    for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    {
      lut->SetTableValue(i, (double)HotMetal[i] / 255.0, (double)HotMetal[256 + i] / 255.0,
                (double)HotMetal[256 * 2 + i] / 255.0, 1.0);
    }`

Comment: It would be the same code, but use `AddRGBPoint` instead of `SetTableValue`.

Comment: I dont know i am doing as you say but the result is not what i expect  Image: http://s1.postimg.org/qfdwz5d0v/Untitled.png Volume should share the color with 2D